# Как создать двумерный массив заполненный dart

Tags: dart

Хотел создать двумерный массив который заполнен чем-то например в питоне:

```py
from random import choice
lst_1 = [1, 2, 3, 5]
lst = [[choice(lst_1) for _ in range(10)] for _ in range(5)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стандартная библиотека *dart* не так богата как в *python*, но аналог функции **choice** можно создать самостоятельно и затем использовать её в генераторе:

```dart
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  final rand = Random();
  final choices = [1, 2, 3, 5];
  final len = choices.length;
  final next = (_) => choices[rand.nextInt(len)];
  final x = List.generate(5, (_) => List.generate(10, next));
  print(x);
}
```